# Angular2: assign component field within #ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have such component:

```
 @Component({
        selector: "expenses-component",
        templateUrl: "expenses.html"
    })
    export default class ExpensesComponent {
        private expenses: [] = [{name: "Foo", amount: 100}, {name: "Bar", amount: 200}];
        private totalAmount: number = 0;
    }
```

and also such template:

```
<h2 class="sub-header">Total: {{total | currency:"USD":true}}</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let expense of expenses | orderByDate; let id = index">
            <td>{{id + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{expense.name}}</td>
            <td>{{expense.amount | currency:"USD":true}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need to count `totalAmount`, but i can't figure out how to do it without providing another one for loop in typescript code, so is there possibility to initialize `total += expense.amount` within the above `#ngFor` loop?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible. You can achieve it by creating custom pipe which will iterate through the array and return totalAmount. As the parameter you can pass the name of the key which you want to use as value.

For the example:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
   name: 'totalAmount'
})

export class totalAmount implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value:any, key:string):any {
       if(value){
          let total = 0;

          for(let i in value){
             total = total + value[i][key];    
          }            

          return total;
    }
    return value;
    }}
```

And then you can call it from html:

```
<div>{{expenses | totalAmount:"amount"}}</div>
```

Comment: In the pipe, you can condense it down to one line using ES6 array.reduce `return value.reduce((a,b) => a + b[key], 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You could make totalAmount a get() method and return it there?

```
private get totalAmount() {
    let total = 0;
    for (let item in this.expenses) {
        total += item.amount;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i could and actually i did it in the same way, but now i try to avoid such approach, because there is already one loop `*ngFor` and i thought i could calculate `totalAmount` within `*ngFor`

Comment: I agree, it's inelegant... but it's good separation of concerns. Rather than trying to use your view code to maintain a total (which may or may not be needed in your component code at some point), it should be managed in the ts file. It's worth considering whether you're prematurely optimising by avoiding doing it this way.